# rsyslog. Filter doesn't work

Tags: logging, ubuntu-10.04, rsyslog

I use ubuntu-server. I try to set filter in my rsyslog.conf for accepting only remote logs from my D-link.

that is debug

```
Debug line with all properties:
FROMHOST: 'fromname', fromhost-ip: '192.168.1.1', HOSTNAME: 'DSR-500N', PRI: 4,
syslogtag 'KERNEL', programname: 'KERNEL', APP-NAME: 'KERNEL', PROCID: '-', MSGID: '-',
TIMESTAMP: 'Oct  2 17:44:08', STRUCTURED-DATA: '-',
msg: ' [Kernel] LOG_PACKET[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN SRC=11.11.11.11 DST=22.22.22.22 PROTO=ESP SPI=0xf9861ec '
escaped msg: ' [Kernel] LOG_PACKET[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN SRC=77.77.77.77 DST=66.66.66.66 PROTO=ESP SPI=0xf9861ec '
rawmsg: '<4>Oct 02 17:44:08 DSR-500N KERNEL [Kernel] LOG_PACKET[ACCEPT]  IN=WAN SRC=44.44.44.44 DST=33.33.33.33 PROTO=ESP SPI=0xf9861ec '
```

And that is my code:

```
if hostname == 'DSR-500N' then  /var/rsyslog/infolog
```

But filter doesn't work. Where I'm wrong?

Thank you!

I tried to change filter. I used this code

```
:$hostname, regex, "*" /var/rsyslog/infolog
```

this is work. But it works for all hostnames. I'd like to filter this, although if I change to

```
:$hostname, regex, "^k" /var/rsyslog/infolog
```

it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$hostname` instead of just `hostname`

```
If $hostname == 'DSR-500N' then /var/rsyslog/infolog
```

Comment: Doesn't help. No errors. Logs doesn't write into file.